# Check if ID exist in another table if yes return TRUE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a grocery Database, Grocery Items Belongs to Category or To a Sub Category and can be part of Favourite List

When I am reading the list of Items from the Category, I would like to include a boolean value to see if the item is part of Favourite list.

Favourite is stored as a combination of Product_ID and USER_ID with a Primary key index id

I have been failed to make the left join for favourite list.

Would really appreciate your support.

Database with data
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/853bd65b90f3a36b4d9264c018bbda9720190409083930/7d620e

```
    Select a.*, ifnull(Deriv1.Count , 0) as Count, ifnull(Total1.PCount, 0) as PCount FROM `categories` a  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `parent`, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `categories` GROUP BY `parent`) Deriv1 ON a.`id` = Deriv1.`parent` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `category_id`,COUNT(*) AS PCount, 
JOIN (SELECT id From Favorite Where userID='1' )  FROM `products` GROUP BY `category_id`) Total1 ON a.`id` = Total1.`category_id` 
WHERE a.`parent`=" . $parent
```

Comment: Is this a working query?

Comment: JOIN (SELECT id From Favorite Where userID='1' )  remove then the sql works

Comment: It's easier to help if you can share the table structure with sample data. with your current query, we don't know what is the relationship between Favourites and Categories

Comment: added the  to the description

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the meaning of retrieving the two 'count columns'. But, still if you just need favourite of user 1 or not, you can use FavouriteOrNot column from this query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, a.id, f.userID, IFNULL(Deriv1.Count , 0) as Count, IFNULL(Total1.PCount, 0) as PCount, IFNULL(f.id, 0) as FavouriteOrNot 
FROM 
`products` p 
INNER JOIN 
`categories` a 
ON 
p.`category_id` = a.`id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT `parent`, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `categories` GROUP BY `parent`) Deriv1 
ON 
a.`id` = Deriv1.`parent` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT `category_id`,COUNT(*) AS PCount FROM `products` GROUP BY `category_id`)Total1 
ON 
a.`id` = Total1.`category_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
`Favorite` f 
ON 
f.`ProductID` = p.`product_id` 
AND 
userID = 1 
WHERE a.`parent`= 1
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" . $parent' at line 16

Comment: i just copy pasted from the original query from the question. I think the query is executed from PHP where the $parent variable is concatenated and so I have updated the query as a string now.

Comment: if you want to execute directly from phpMyAdmin replace the parent variable with any value that you want to filter on.

Comment: yes, I did the same. getting the same error 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" 0' at line 16

Comment: did you remove the double quote?

Comment: The Favourite is stored as a combination of Product ID and User ID 
a.'id' is category id. I think we must also relace a.id to Total1.product_id.

isn't it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191513/discussion-between-sabhari-karthik-and-speedracer).

Comment: userID='1' in the query is also ignored. i am getting FavouriteOrNot value !=0 for all ids irrespective of to which user it belongs to. 

And for Parent ID 2 Entries are fetched more than once